# How to import WriteBatch from Firebase in Angular>

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I'm using this packages to handle Firebase in my Angular App:

```
"@angular/fire": "^6.1.4",
"firebase": "^8.2.7",
```

I created a service to handle Batch operations:

```
import { WriteBatch } from 'firebase/firestore'; // Does not work
import { WriteBatch } from 'firebase'; // Does not work

export class FireStoreBatch {
  private _batch: WriteBatch;

  public Create(): void{
    this._batch = this.afs.firestore.batch();
  }

}
```

[image]

Which import do I need to add to be able to use WriteBatch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across the same problem, as I wanted to pass the WriteBatch as a parameter to a function. I did not find a fitting import, but was able to pass the `WriteBatch` using `FirebaseFirestore.WriteBatch`.

```
export const myFunction = (batch: FirebaseFirestore.WriteBatch) => {
  // do something
}
```

Just by the look of it, this should also work for your code:

```
export class FireStoreBatch {
  private _batch: FirebaseFirestore.WriteBatch;

  public Create(): void{
    this._batch = this.afs.firestore.batch();
  }

}
```